# What does 's' stand for in this definition of Fractional Brownian Motion?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

[image]

It's taken from Mandelbrot & Van Ness' (1968) definition of Fractional Brownian Motion. I believe it is a definition of the difference between values of the process at t1 and t2, but I don't understand why the RHS refers to t without a subscript and s. I want to know this because I would like to see how the covariance:
[image]
is derived from the above definition.

Comment: I'm thinking of asking this on the math exchange so to whom it may concern: feel free to delete it, if there's some policy against double posts.

Comment: `s` is the variable of integration. The error is `t`. The good formula is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion#Background_and_definition).